# Setting the isolated scope as a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm not sure if this is definitely possible, but basically I am trying to set the isolated scope on my directive to a variable that will be pulled in from an array in the controller.

Directive:

```
app.directive('ydConfig', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tag: '='
        },
        templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
              return attrs['template'];
        }
    };
});
```

Arrays in controller:

```
$scope.configHead = ['style', 'color', 'glass', 'details'];
$scope.activeTabs = ['style'];
$scope.configType = $scope.activeTabs[0];
```

HTML:

```
<yd-config tag="style" template="/app/views/yd-config-item.html" ng-if="isTabOpen('style')" ng-class="{right : direction, left : !direction}" ng-animate class="{{configType}}"></yd-config>
```

Basically, configHead is an array with all the scopes that yd-config will end up using as the user cycles through yd-config with a toggle. activeTabs usually contains one object, but sometimes contains two while yd-config is in process of changing scope and data. configType exists so that I can target the currently active scope and access it in the DOM.

In my HTML, is there a way I can change "style" in the tag isolated scope to be configType? I have tried {{configType}} both with and without a prefixed $scope, and I have tried it without the double curly brackets, but I always get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=configType&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7BconfigType%7D%7D&p4=configType%7D%7D).

How would I also put configType into the ng-if so that my yd-config is completely generic? At the minute I have 4 yd-configs one after another in the DOM, each with different tags and ng-if's (and, until just before I created this ticket, different classes too).

Is my best option going to be to create a function that returns the configType and just target the function from those parts of the directive?

I have seen [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkqUn/3/) from a previous question on SO, so I know it is possible, but why am I getting the error when I try the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've tried should've worked. You can pass `$scope.configType` to the directive with `tag="configType"` and use it in the ng-if like so `ng-if="isTabOpen(configType)"`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.configHead = ['style', 'color', 'glass', 'details'];
  $scope.activeTabs = ['style'];
  $scope.configType = $scope.activeTabs[0];
  
  $scope.isTabOpen = function (tab) {
    return $scope.activeTabs.indexOf(tab) != -1
  }
});

app.directive('ydConfig', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tag: '='
        },
        /*templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
              return attrs['template'];
        }*/
        template: '<span>{{ tag }}</span>'
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <yd-config tag="configType" ng-if="isTabOpen(configType)"></yd-config>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It couldn't have anything to do with the directive having an isolated scope, while configType is set to the parent scope, could it? Would that change the syntax when adding it to 'tag'? I'm at a point now where all of it is working except for the scope, but it seems a shame to have to list that directive 4 times in the DOM just because of this. It'd be much cleaner if it was fully generic :/

Comment: Ok, the issue here is evidently slightly different than I expected.  I am also now getting the dupes error instead of a syntax error.

I tried running this again, but instead of my templateUrl, I used the template you had in the example and it is outputting the correct tag when I click on my toggles. I'm wondering now if it has something to do with the way I am either calling the template, or with the actual template itself.

Template:

`<li ng-repeat="item in configType" id="{{item.id}}" ng-animate="'animate'">
    <img ng-src="{{item.image}}" />
    <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
</li>`

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to repeat as `configType` is just a string value? You might want to post a jsfiddle of what you've got so far.

Comment: Ok, sorry, THIS is essentially what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/louisemcc/kdwau5c7/9/

So essentially the JS is now working correctly, but I am not targeting the content properly so even though the template is there, the content is not filling it. How should I target the content?

Comment: When I said repeat, what I meant was I used to have:  

`<yd-config tag="style" ng-if="isTabOpen('style')" ng-class="{right : direction, left : !direction}" class="style" ng-animate=""></yd-config>  
<yd-config tag="color" ng-if="isTabOpen('color')" ng-class="{right : direction, left : !direction}" class="color" ng-animate=""></yd-config>` etc  

When I wanted to have:   

`<yd-config tag="configType" ng-if="isTabOpen(configType)" ng-class="{right : direction, left : !direction}" class="{{configType}}" ng-animate=""></yd-config>`

Comment: Ah right I see. The problem is that in your directive `tag` isn't any reference at all to `$scope.style`, it is just the string `'style'`. As a quick fix you could change the repeat to `ng-repeat="item in $parent[tag]` but this kind of defeats the point of an isolate scope. Personally I'd change to something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gqLgxsr/1/) using a single object to hold your lists then pass the selected one to your directive

Comment: Thank you for all your help :) This is now working, but I've encountered a separate issue - because this is no longer powered by ng-if and is instead picking up different scopes, how can I animate the change of scope? Previously I was animating ng-enter/ng-leave, but now as there is no ng-if, these classes are not available to use.

Comment: No worries. You should still be able to animate the individual <li> items? If not, [set up a repeat](http://jsfiddle.net/6gqLgxsr/2/) so each `yd-config` is a separate element

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Got moved onto something else for a bit. I have this all working now though so thanks very much for your help :) I've set your answer as correct and tried to upvote but I don't have the experience yet so I will come back and upvote you once I do :)